# Compose functions into another function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Is there a function for Haskell in the standard library which takes three functions and returns a function which applies the return values of the first two functions to the third function, something like this:

```
compact :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (b -> c -> d) -> a -> d
compact a b c = \x -> c (a x) (b x)
```

Or this:

```
import Control.Arrow
compact' :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (b -> c -> d) -> a -> d
compact' a b c = uncurry c . (a &&& b)
```

So that:

```
compact (take 1) (drop 2) (++) [1,2,3,4] == [1,3,4]
compact (+10) (*2) (<) 11 == True
compact (+10) (*2) (<) 9 == False
```

Comment: that's also `c . a <*> b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reorder the signature to:

```
(b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> d
```

this is equivalent to [`liftM2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2), since [`((->) r)` is an instance of Monad type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-645)

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
```

and

```
\> liftM2 (++) (take 1) (drop 2) [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1,3,4]
```

---

similarly, [`liftA2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2) from `Control.Applicative`:

```
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c

\> liftA2 (++) (take 1) (drop 2) [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1,3,4]
```

Comment: or if you want to get familiar with `Applicative`, you can use `<*>` to generalize this to functions of arbitrary arity: `(++) <$> take 1 <*> drop 2` is the same as `liftA2 (++) (take 1) (drop 2)`.

Answer (score 4):

`liftM2` from `Control.Monad` is almost the same as your `compact` function, just with the arguments in a different order.

`liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r`

which in context is the same as:

`liftM2 :: (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> d`

So:

```
liftM2 (++) (take 1) (drop 2) [1,2,3,4] == [1,3,4]
liftM2 (<) (+10) (*2) 11 == True
liftM2 (<) (+10) (*2) 9 == False
```